# Android, start skype call within your app with skype 4.0

Tags: android, android-intent, skype

I have an Android app which launches a call to a mobile number using skype.

The app was working, but now skype has released his version 4.0 of the android app, and my app doesn't make call using skype anymore..

I'm using the following code to start the call:

```
Intent sky = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sky.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + numero));
    sky.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
    sky.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//Log.i(LOG_TAG, "skype chiamo:" + numero);
startActivity(sky);
```

Does anyone knows if something is changed or if I am doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot!!

**EDIT WORKING CODE:**

```
Intent sky = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sky.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + number+"?call"));
sky.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
sky.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(sky);
```

Comment: I think, they just broke the app and there is nothing you can do, but waiting for an update.